# Changing Column in MySQL from int to double?

Tags: mysql, syntax, int, double

Basically, I currently have a column in a MySQL table, which is an int.

I'd like to change that to double. I've searched the web, but all it came up with was conversion upon getting the values from the column (like converting some date to Date), but that's not what I mean.

I'm guessing it's something with Alter Table, and I looked that up on the MySQL dev page, but could not find what I was looking for.

Comment: I presume you mean "column", not "row"?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's the real syntax. Make sure to set the nullability appropriately too:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
MODIFY COLUMN your_column DOUBLE NULL;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
MODIFY COLUMN your_column DOUBLE NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Nullability is optional in a [***`column_definition`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) - it defaults to `NULL` if not specified; why not argue all the other optional attributes should also be specified in place of accepting their defaults?

Comment: I'm trying to help the OP avoid accidentally changing the nullability when they change the data type. Certainly the same holds true for default values, etc. but I was trying to address the most likely scenario. If the original column was NOT NULL and the OP uses your answer, then the column will change to NULL.

Comment: Thanks Ike - I think that explanation is very helpful (hopefully to the OP too).  +1

Comment: Will this delete the current content of the column?

Comment: @ThomasAhle this will preserve the existing column values, implicitly converting them from INT to DOUBLE.

Answer (score 5):

You're right that you need to use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).  The command will look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN columnname DOUBLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

My SQL is Non-case sensitive. You can use:

```
 ALTER or alter, TABLE or table, COLUMN or column, DOUBLE or double
```

Right now, you follow this format:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name DOUBLE;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).